# django admin tinymce for part of textareas

Tags: django, django-admin, tinymce, django-tinymce

I'm using django admin + grappelli + tinymce from grappelli.

It works perfect, but I can't figure out how to make an admin form with textareas and apply tinymce only for part of them.

For example, I've two fields: description and meta-description. I need tinymce only for description and I need textarea without tinymce for meta-descrption.

tinymce in admin is enabled via form like this:

```
class AdminForm(forms.ModelForm):      
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):      
        """Sets the list of tags to be a string"""      
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        if instance:
            init = kwargs.get('initial', {})
            kwargs['initial'] = init

        super(AdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Media:
            js = (
                     settings.STATIC_URL + 'grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
                     settings.STATIC_URL + 'grappelli/tinymce_setup/tinymce_setup.js',
            )
```

and enabled in admin.py:

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AdminForm
```

It looks like behaviour is described in the beginning of tinymce init:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: 'textareas',
    theme: 'advanced',
    skin: 'grappelli',
    ...
```

Is there a way to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the mode to `textareas`, it won't give you any sort of selector control as to which one it applies the editor to. You'll most likely need to drop the `mode` setting and go with `selector`: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:selector

The django-tinymce config options are just a mirror for [TinyMCE's settings](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration).

Answer (score 0):

On a field by field basis you can use this technique providing a custom ModelForm:

```
class XAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100,
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '100'}))
    something = forms.CharField(label='Something', max_length=SOME_MAX_LENGTH,
                      widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': '10', 'cols': '100'}))
    note = forms.CharField(label='Note', max_length=NOTE_MAX_LENGTH,
                   widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'ckeditor'}))
class Meta:
    model = x

class Meta:
    model = x


class XAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = X
    form = XAdminForm

    class Media:
        js = ('/static/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js',)
admin.site.register(X, XAdmin)
```